# PreparedStatement + Select for update + Oracle 12c + ORA-01461 in primary key column

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, ora-01461

I have a strange problem when trying to execute a select for update statement and then execute subsequently an insert or update. I get an [ORA-01461](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01461_can_bind_a_long_value_only_for_insert_into_a_long_column.htm) exception. This happens only when using the latest ojdbc driver ([12.1.0.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html)), while in the older one it works fine ([12.1.0.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html)).

More specifically the latest driver seems to have some kind of limit in primary key character length (limited to 32 chars) although the corresponding column is declared more than 32 chars. Sample code to replicate the problem is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_TABLE" (
 "TEST_ID" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
 "TEST_COMMENT" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR),
 CONSTRAINT "TEST_TABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("TEST_ID")
);
```

And some java:

```
public class DemoUpdatableResultSet {

    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1521/xxxxx";
    private static final String DB_USER = "xxx";
    private static final String DB_PASS = "xxx";

  public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    return conn;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
      conn = getConnection();
      String query = "SELECT t.* FROM TEST_TABLE t WHERE t.TEST_ID=? FOR UPDATE";
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
          ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
      pstmt.setString(1, uuid); // set input values
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); // create an updatable ResultSet
                                               // insert column values into the insert row.
      rs.moveToInsertRow();                    // moves cursor to the insert row
      rs.updateString("TEST_ID", uuid);           // updates the 2nd column
      rs.updateString("TEST_COMMENT", "Comment for: " + uuid);
      rs.insertRow();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

First line of main method creates a uuid

```
 UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

which is 36 chars long. Running this sample class will produce an ORA-01461 error, but changing the line mentioned above to

```
 UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
```

which yields to 32 chars string will run correctly and insert the row in the database. Notice that the "TEST_ID" column in which the above string is saved is VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) and can accommodate both 32 and 36 chars strings. Increasing the column's length to even greater numbers won't change anything.

I hope my sample code is easy to read and understand and I am looking forward for a solution/explanation to this problem.

Thanks!

Database Info:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

Modified slightly to run an insert statement with the same data to show that this problem is more weird than it seems (regarding the uuid string length). The following sample code executes correctly with the newest oracle driver:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
      conn = getConnection();
      String query = "INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TEST_ID, TEST_COMMENT) VALUES (?, ?)";
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      pstmt.setString(1, uuid); // set input values
      pstmt.setString(2, "Comment for: " + uuid); // set input values
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, edited my first post and added database info. Thanks!

Comment: Could you try to replace the hyphen symbol with another character (for example `0` or `a`) rather than empty string? Just to understand if the problem is really the size...What happens?

Comment: Sure, just tried it, the same error occurs ORA-01461, please see my edit with the new main function which does an insert.

Comment: Are you using the JDBC Driver from 12c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opened an SR to oracle since this is a bug of 12.1.0.2.0 jdbc driver and would need a patch to resolve it.

Comment: Just for future reference, bug number is [Bug 22385253 : RESULTSET.INSERTROW METHOD WITH JDBC 12.1.0.2.0 THROWS ORA-1461](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=22385253)

Answer (score -2):

This error occurs trying to use a varchar variable longer than 4000 bytes in an SQL statement (4000 bytes is the limit).

You should check what the `uuid` variable contains paying attention to possible encoding.

Anyway store the UUID like VARCHAR datatype is not a good idea.

The workaround to make it work could be change the `TEST_ID` datatype from `VARCHAR2` to `CLOB` (removing the PK like you said in the comment below) but this is not the solution.

Comment: Your solution did not work. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @yannisf No since i'm on mobile now but in the past i got the same problem. Did you already try to change the datatype in `VARBINARY(36)`? Does the result is the same?

Comment: @Satoshi Kouno: Your answer is the most obvious, but sorry this is not the case. uuid is exactly 36 characters long, if you run an insert statement with the same data in SQL Developer the row is inserted with no errors. And in my first post I mention that if you trim 4 characters from the uuid then the sample code inserts the row correctly.

Comment: And CLOB as primary key is not supported in Oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADLOB/adlob_working.htm#ADLOB2010)

Comment: @elefasGR Like i said, the **CLOB is a workaround and not the solution**. In any case for me is wrong store the UUID using `VARCHAR` since this affect the performance.

Comment: @Satoshi Kouno: edited my first post with a new main function this time doing an insert statement instead for a select for update. This time the insert statement executes correctly so it can't be the column's datatype, length etc.